# Why is there a 10 after I print a char array?

Tags: c, input

I would like to know, why there is always a 10 at the end of my print.

I am trying to get input of a string with spaces, then print all the chars out.

Input: `hello`

outputting: `104 101 108 108 111 10`

should output: `104 101 108 108 111`

```
  unsigned char input[256];
  fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);

  for(int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    printf("%u ",input[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Um, watch your fingers when you type ... is the last key they hit 'o', or something else?

Comment: Answers mentioning that 10 is the encoding of the character passed for the ENTER key are correct, except that they cite ASCII. We don't know what character set and encoding your console is using but it's probably not ASCII. By design, many character sets are supersets of ASCII and most of their encodings are identical to ASCII for the common subset. Find out what you are really using with `locale` in Linux and `chcp` in Windows. And, keep in mind that uses of your program could be using something different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`10` is a newline.  `fgets` consumes the newline *and* copies it to the buffer. From [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets):

> Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.

The documentation is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII code 10 is newline (\n):

http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/line-feed-ascii-code-10.html

Maybe you are reading string from a file?

Comment: What, you think lines entered from the console don't end with a newline?

Answer (score 1):

You're printing out the newline character.

This is represented as the number `10` (ASCII) when you print it out.

Answer (score 1):

10 Is The ASCII code for the new line (\n)

Answer (score 1):

The end of line `'\n'` has code 10 in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Notice that 6 numbers printed out.  Bet you type 6 keys:

<kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

So the input was not "hello", but `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `'\n'`.

`fgets()` read those 6 and save them in `input[]`.  It also appended a `'\0'`, so 7 `char` were saved.